# Java: Splitting a string

Tags: java

In java I have a method that recieves a string that looks like:

> "Name ID CSVofInts"

It's purpose is to create a new object with the name, ID and then pass in the CSV as an int array.

How do you split such a string?

Comment: Can you show a couple example rows?  I'm wondering if the Name, ID, and CSV data have any extra spaces, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String items [] = str.split(" ", 3);
String csv [] = items[2].split(",");
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Number of approaches:

```
String[] splitArrayOfStrings = theString.split("delimiter");
```

Or

You could utilize the `StringTokenizer` class for more flexible handling

Answer (score 1):

you can use the tokenizer class.

EX:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

will output

```
this
is
a
test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Java string [split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function.

---

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these expressions:

Regex -> `":"`

Result ->

```
{ "boo", "and", "foo" }
```

Returns an array of strings. :)

Answer (score 0):

Chop off the first two fields by simply iterating over the string and finding the first two words, then the ints can be split with `substring.split(",");`